# Openshift: changing app-root with ssh and updating git

Tags: ruby, git, ssh, openshift

I'm new to Openshift and tried to update the database directly using `ssh` and `rake db:migrate` to create the tables, I did this on `app-root/repo`.

That's also where the problem begins, first I don't know how to update git with these changes,
secondly I won't be able to push either using a different repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All changes to your application should be made to your local git repository first and then added, committed, pushed with Git. From there Openshift will handle the rest (including a rake db:migrate). For instance here's how I normally do ruby development for my OpenShift applications.

1. From the command line of your local machine run the following to create your application:

`$ rhc app create awesomeapp ruby-2.0 mysql-5.5`

2. Once the application is finished cd into the repo that was automatically cloned locally for you:

`$ cd awesomeapp`

3. Make your ruby changes (add models, views, etc.)
4. Update your db locally to test changes:
   `$ rake db:migrate`
5. Once you're satisfied the next steps are to add, commit, push your changes:

`$ git add .`
`$ git commit -am "I made some stuff"`
`$ git push`

6. You should then start to see a bunch of deploy output concerning your gear. If you look closely you should see that a `rake db:migrate` was automatically done for you on your local gear.